# Detecting Invalid Dates in Oracle 11g database (ORA-01847 )

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I am querying an Oracle 11.2 instance to build a small data mart that includes extracting the date of birth and date of death of people.

Unfortunately the INSERT query (which takes its data from a SELECT) fails due to ORA-01847 (day of month must be between 1 and last day of month).

To find my bad dates I first did:

```
SELECT extract(day FROM SOME_DT_TM), 
       extract(month FROM SOME_DT_TM),
       COUNT(*)
  FROM PERSON
 GROUP BY extract(day FROM SOME_DT_TM), extract(month FROM SOME_DT_TM)
 ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC;
```

It gave me 367 rows, one for each day of the year including NULL and February-29th (leap year). True for the other date column as well, so it looks like the data is fine from a `SELECT` perspective.

However if I set logging up on my insert

```
 create table registry_new_dates 
                 (some_dob date, some_death_date date);
 exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log('SOME_NEW_DATES');
```

And then run my long insert query:

```
SELECT some_dob,some_death_date,ora_err_mesg$ FROM ERR$_SOME_NEW_DATES;
```

I get the following weird results (first 3 rows shown) which makes me think that zip codes have been somehow inserted instead of dates for the 2nd column.

```
31-DEC-25  35244  "ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
13-DEC-33  35244-3402  "ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
23-JUN-58  35235  "ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
```

My question is - how do I detect these bad rows (there are 11 apparentlyh) with an SQL statement so I can fix or remove them. Fixing them in the originating table is not an option (no write privileges). I tried using queries like this:

```
SELECT DECEASED_DT_TM 
  FROM WH_CLN_PERSON 
 WHERE DECEASED_DT_TM LIKE '35%' 
   AND rownum<3;
```

But it did not find the offending rows.

Comment: What is the datatype of deceased_dt_tm?

Comment: A first approach would be to insert the dates along with the primary person key into a temp table. You should still get the errors on that insert, but the primary key would then let you inspect the apparently-bad rows to see what's up. Once you know the way in which they're bad you can look for an approach to fix or filter them.

Comment: DECEASED_DT_TM is a Date

Comment: Zastai, that is a good idea, I will try that and post when I get results.

Comment: Took awhile to run - but I got the primary key and investigated the records. It adds to the mystery because 3 of the records have actual legitimate looking dates and the other records have (null) entries for that column.

Comment: If deceased_dt_tm is a date, and you treat it as such, as opposed to a string, you should not have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still actively researching this (or if you got an answer already).

To find the rows with the bad data, can't you instead select the DOB *and* the date of death, and express the WHERE clause in terms of DOB - like so:
...WHERE some_dob = to_date('31-DEC-25')
?  After you find those rows, you may want to do another query on just one or two of those rows, including a calculated column:   dump(date of death). Then post that. We can learn a lot from the dump - the internal representation of the so-called "date" (which may very well be a ZIP code instead). With that in hand we may be able to figure out what's stored, and how to hunt for it.

Comment: I'm good now, I used the tip for Zastai to find the offending rows.